Raspberry Pi 4b emulation for github actions
I am trying to use an emulation of a Raspberry Pi to do sensors testing.
I am currently working on a group project on Raspberry Pi 4b, but we only have 1 for a team of 8. I wanted to install a GitHub action for CI and testing. We have some packages cpp packages like pigpio.h (https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio) that only compile and run on Raspberry Pi. I am using https://github.com/pguyot/arm-runner-action to compile and run in my CI. The issue is that at the init pigpio, using the cpu_info: flag I can make it think it  is running on Raspberry Pi 4b, but then I get :
./ADXL375_test 2024-04-15 15:03:02 initAllocDMAMem: mbox open failed(No such device or address) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Adxl375Exception' what():  Communication failure. 2024-04-15 15:03:02 sigHandler: Unhandled signal 6, terminating
I assume it is because it can't communicate with GPIO, is this the case? If so, what can I do to address this issue?
Thank you for your time.
